# Redirect output to a file using dub2(): undefined reference to `dub2'

Tags: c, linux, linker, ld, unistd.h

I'm implementing a simple shell, I'm trying to use system call "open" and copy the file descriptor using "dub2" system call. When I compile I always get:

```
undefined reference to `dub2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

  //input line would be "ls > testfile.txt"

  char* input1 = "ls";
  char* input2 = ">";
  char* input3 = "testfile.txt";

  int f = open(input3, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
  dub2(f, 1);     //1(stdout)

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the function name.

It's `dup2`, not `dub2`.

Comment: I can see that now, I've been staring at the screen for more than two hours not understanding whats wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't get a warning about "implicit declaration of dub2", consider turning up the warning level on your compiler